# How to improve my battle system?

Tags: game-mechanics

I'm coding this little game and I need help with my battle system. I don't have any idea how to improve my system. I made it like RANDOM_VALUE VS RANDOM_VALUE. It's a console game, so I need console BS ideas.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main () {
      SetConsoleTitle("Battle game");
      int i, y, jidlo, soused, random, uder1;
      
      ////Battle system
      random = rand() % 5 + 1;
      uder1 = rand() % 8 + 1;

      system("pause");
      system("CLS");
      cout << "BOJ ZACAL!"<< endl;
      system("pause");
      system("CLS");
    
      if(uder1 >= random) {
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
        cout << "You won and earned 3 crowns!" << endl;
      }
      else {
        cout << "You lost!" << endl;
        system("restart");
      }
      system("pause>nul");
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Try asking something more specific instead of "how to improve?".

Comment: Hi SkIT, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange! For questions about the design of mechanics, I recommend checking out the [tag guidance on the `game-design` tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info). It lists 4 things you should edit your question to cover: 1) Establish the context of your game (genre, audience, main mechanics) 2) Describe the feature you need help with, and how it works currently 3) Define a desired outcome - what should this feature accomplish or feel like when it's been "improved" to your liking? 4) Ask for a strategy to achieve this outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a few ways to "improve" this system. It's functional as is so nothing is really needed but here are a few ideas.

1. Give each attacker some value of hit points (if you imagine a game like Risk we'd talk about armies). Then loop through the attack as you have it now for each round the loser looses some hit points until one of them reaches zero. That give a nice look too with a "You took 2 damage and have 7 health remaining." or "You dealt 2 damage, your opponent has 9 health remaining." or what have you.
2. Each attacker could have a separate attack and defend "roll"  in that way each attacker would attack every round so it would be possible for both to take damage.

This list could quite literally go on forever. But hopefully these ideas would provide some inspiration.